# Convert UIimage (take a picture) to NSData

Tags: image, swift

I used this method to take a picture.

```
func convertImageFromCMSampleBufferRef(sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> CIImage{
    let pixelBuffer:CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!;
    let ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

    if done == true {

        newImage =  UIImage(CIImage:ciImage, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .DownMirrored)

        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.6)
        var compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!, nil, nil, nil)       
    }

    return ciImage;
}
```

The code should work, but the variable `imageData = nil`
I tried converting the image in PNG, but with the same result.

with print

> newImage = , {720, 1280} imageData = nil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must convert CIImage to a CGImage, then CGImage to an UIImage, and then UIImage to NSData.

```
static let context = CIContext(options:nil);
let tempImage:CGImageRef = context.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent())
let image = UIImage(CGImage: tempImage);
let imageData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6);
```

Comment: in let originalImage = CIImage(image: ciImage); Cannot convert value of type 'CIImage' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: Does anyone know the best way to convert the data back into a CIImage?